# @RolesAllowed has no effect on my RESTful Service

Tags: java, rest, security, wildfly, jaas

I'm having some trouble with setting up my secure REST-Service.
I wanted to create a simple login/logout service and mess around with it.

I was following this tutorial. I skipped the part with the login form and hardcoded the username and password into the service. (login())
http://www.blog.btbw.pl/java/wildfly-9-login-form-simple-example/

It all worked fine until I wanted to use the annotation @RolesAllowed.
So I created a new method (adminInfo()) with this annotation. But I came to the conclusion that the annotation made no difference. I was able to call it successfully without being loggedin with the role "ADMIN".

Maybe one of you intelligent people outside know what I did wrong and is able to help me. Sorry for my bad grammar, I'm not used to write so much in english.

Thank you.

These are my files:

I'm using a simple Service which looks like this:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GET
@Path("/hello")
public Response hello() {
    return Response.ok().entity("Hello, World!").build();
}

@GET
@Path("/logout")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public Response adminInfo() {
    return Response.ok().entity("hello " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName()).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/login")
public Response login() {
    try {
        request.login("admin", "admin");
        return Response.ok().entity("login successful").build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("login failed").build();
    }
}

@GET
@Path("/logout")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public Response logout() {
    try {
        request.logout();
        return Response.ok().entity("logout successful").build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("logout failed").build();
    }
}
```

My jboss-web.xml looks like this:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <security-domain>jaas-realm</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

And my web.xml looks as following:

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jaas-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

My Wildfly standalone.xml is configured like this:

```
<security-domain name="jaas-realm" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module name="login-module" code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/datasource"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where username=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select rolename, 'Roles' from roles where username=?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it finally work. I had to add the annotation `@Stateless` to my Service.
Thanks to a post that was made 5 years ago:
[JAX-WS webservice and @rolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080299/jax-ws-webservice-and-rolesallowed)

I wasn't able to find the solution on Google, but 5 mins on Stackoverflow was all I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two resources with same path as `@Path("/logout")`. A resource is uniquely identified by its PATH. Please have different paths and try

Comment: Thank you, I made a stupid copypasta. I changed it but it still doesn't work.